# SQL JOIN only one match

Tags: sql

We have three tables: podcasts (podcast_id, title), reviews (podcast_id, rating, review_title, author_id) and categories (podcast_id, category).

When I join these tables, I get some podcasts and reviews twice because in the categories table some podcast_ids are listed twice as they have two corresponding categories.

In fact I need only one category per podcast, how can I join tables picking only one category per podcast from the categories table? I need to keep all reviews, so GROUP BY podcasts.title won't do.

This is the query I'm currently running:

```
SELECT podcasts.title AS podcast,
categories.category,
reviews.title AS review,
reviews.rating,
reviews.author_id
FROM podcasts
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews ON reviews.podcast_id = podcasts.podcast_id
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.podcast_id = podcasts.podcast_id
```

Comment: What is the SQL query that you are currently running?

Comment: You can use Group by to eliminate duplicates

Comment: @Kleo G
SELECT podcasts.title AS podcast,
                                    categories.category,
                                    reviews.title AS review,
                                    reviews.rating,
                                    reviews.author_id
                                    FROM podcasts
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews ON reviews.podcast_id = podcasts.podcast_id
                                    LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.podcast_id = podcasts.podcast_id

Comment: @Subhashis Padey If I group by, I miss reviews and I want to keep all reviews.

Comment: If you have 2 categories per ID that are different, which category should be shown? If they are the same just use select distinct. Sample data in your question (see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) will help.

Comment: @Stu thank you for the hint! This is my query, not sure if DISTINCT helpsSELECT podcasts.title AS podcast,
                                    categories.category,
                                    reviews.title AS review,
                                    reviews.rating,
                                    reviews.author_id
                                    FROM podcasts
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews ON reviews.podcast_id = podcasts.podcast_id
                                    LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.podcast_id = podcasts.podcast_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So which category do you want to throw away? If you don't care you can use this:

```
SELECT podcasts.title AS podcast,
C.category,
reviews.title AS review,
reviews.rating,
reviews.author_id
FROM podcasts
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews ON reviews.podcast_id = podcasts.podcast_id
LEFT JOIN (
     select podcast_id, MAX(category) as category 
     from  categories 
     group by podcast_id
     ) C
 ON C.podcast_id = podcasts.podcast_id
```

Comment: MAX is picking the last one and MIN the first one. Is it possile to pick a category with the shortest name?

Comment: I found the answer myself: LEFT JOIN (
     select podcast_id, category
     from  categories
     group by podcast_id
     HAVING LENGTH(category) = MIN(LENGTH(category))
     ) C

Comment: This is why it is important to explain the whole situation up front inyour original question.  Have you tested your solution for when you have two categories the same min length?

Comment: Probably there were no cases when category names had the same length because I get the same number of rows with the `MAX(category) as category` solution and with the `MIN(LENGTH(category))` solution. On the other hand in both cases I have some duplicates which I found in the dataframe with `reviews[reviews[['podcast','review','rating','author_id']].duplicated(keep=False)]`

Comment: THe MAX solution will always work regardless. The min(length(category)) solution will cause duplicates if you ever have two categories the same length _in future_. I recommend removing this bug now rather than letting it randomly causing you an issue in future.

Answer (score 0):

if you have two entries with the same values then use the distinct keyword this will help you eliminate out the other occurrence.